# Export bulk files from the Amazon S3 bucket on single action or click in salesforce custom Object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I want to download multiple files from my Amazon s3 bucket on a single button click. Is there any procedure to achieve this functionality. I am having files in amazon s3 bucket for one of the custom object and on click of the button I want to save these multiple files to my local system.

(Update) 
Basically I am having a custom object in salesforce in which we can upload the files to Amazon s3 from salesforce.

Now we want to download the files from the same bucket to our local machine. Under the salesforce custom object for these files, we have some information like url, name of the files , etc.

Now i want the list of all the files associated with the parent s3 object and then download multiple selected files to the system directly

Comment: What have you done so far? Please be more specific.

Comment: mootmoot,
  Basically I am having a custom object in salesforce in which we can upload the files to Amazon s3 from salesforce and now we want to download the files from the same bucket to our local machine. under the custom object for these s3 files we have some information like there url, name of the files etc and Now i want the list of all the files associated with the parent object and then download multiple selected files to the system directly.

Comment: I just put your comment into the edited question. After the peer review, you should see it. Or you can put your updated information yourself directly.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your salesforce API and see whether it allow you to retrieve the associate S3 object information

Second, You need to know how the custom object format and how the file is store in S3.

Then you just checkout the AWS SDK  that your developer familiar with, reference form the object and download those file with your own custom script.

Since you say the salesforce object already contains url, name of the file, you can just go directly to that S3 bucket with your AWS access , inspect them and decide the download strategy. As long as you own the S3 bucket (if you are not subscribe to a locked services), you can do anything you like.